# React conditional action - useEffect vs an if statement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Relatively new to React and ran into something that I wasn't sure the answer about. If you have a conditional action, is there a difference between `useEffect` and just having the if statement?

```
function Items() {
    [setItemAdded, itemAdded] = useState(false);
    
    if (itemAdded) {
      saveData();
      itemAdded = false;
    }

}
```

vs

```
     useEffect(() => {
         if (itemAdded) {
             saveData();
             itemAdded = false;
         }, [itemAdded]);
```

From my understanding, when the state updates `itemAdded`, it will re-render the component which would call the conditional statement and execute the code.

In the 2nd case, since `itemAdded` is a dependency it will get called whenever `itemAdded` is changed. To me, both scenarios seem to have the same effect. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: `itemAdded = false` is a misuse of the `useState` hook. `itemAdded` will be a setter function that sets the state value of `setItemAdded`. Maybe that looks confusing but that's because you chose poor names for the value and the setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, and you will see the difference by adding another state and updating it.

**if statement** is getting executed on every render but `useEffect` is only getting executed according to its dependency (item in the array).

I recommend using **useEffect** instead of **if statement**